# XPath to select an element based on string values of multiple children?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to find an element based on the attributes of multiple children.
This is what I have so far

```
//div[a[contains(text(),"Liquid")] and a[contains(text(),"Orange")]]
```

This is what I want to find

```
<div class="inner-article">
    <a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/hats/jjklos2it/cacyn7gr5"
        <img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/158414/vi/iDhLpmX68d4.jpg" alt="Idhlpmx68d4">
        <div class="sold_out_tag">sold out</div>
    </a>
    <h1>
        <a class="name-link" href="/shop/hats/jjklos2it/cacyn7gr5">Liquid Silk Camp Cap</a>
    </h1>
    <p>
        <a class="name-link" href="/shop/hats/jjklos2it/cacyn7gr5">Orange</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

In conclusion, I want to find the div with both 'Liquid' and 'Orange' children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those links are not *children*, but *descendants*, so try

```
//div[.//a[contains(text(),"Liquid")] and .//a[contains(text(),"Orange")]]
```

Comment: Thank you, how would I make it so the code also specifically chooses the div with the class "inner-article".

Comment: @RishiPatel , `//div[@class="inner-article" and .//a[contains(text(),"Liquid")] and .//a[contains(text(),"Orange")]]`. Don't forget to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem